# Async processing J2EE

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, jakarta-ee, asynchronous

In Servlet 3.0 the concept of async processing was introduced. So all the books says that eliminates the requirement one thread per request. I have tested that and yeah, it actually works. Now, I have a simple servlet where users initiate an HTTP request, in sync mode. The thread is simply sleeps for 1 second and then replies to the client. When I do a load testing against this mode, the server can handle 4 request per second only. 
Now, I change the sync mode to async mode and create a new thread on request an release the original http thread back to pool. Again, the new thread initiated sleeps for 1 second and replies back.That mode however, scales very good, it handles hundreds of requests per second.

Now, the question is, all the books and articles says the server has limited number of recourses so keeping one thread per request is not good. etc. In both scenarios, I have one thread per request, the main difference is in first one it is an http thread and in the second one it is my custom thread. Now the question is, is there anything special about the HTTP threads than my custom threads? After all, in both case we have the one thread per request, why the first one performs bad but the second one does not? I have gone through many documents, books none explains that tricky detail. Can you suggest me something? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no difference between HTTP threads and Asychronous Threads...

You see a performance upgrade is because HTTP threads (mostly) are implemented as a fixed N-size pool of threads; meaning that at last N server requests will be processed concurrently... any other requests will block (or rejected) until one or more threads become free.

In the Asynchronous mode, those N threads are used and released very quickly because the hard work (creating the response object) is being done in another thread(s); allowing you to continue receiving more hit requests.

Depending how you implement the background threads, you will see the performance upgrade. For example, if you also implement your threads as a  fixed M-size pool, where M is bigger than N, you will see an increment of `M - N` requests in processing.